# My focus event listener is not getting triggered

Tags: javascript

When i try to fire a event listener in js for an input element it is not getting called.
This is how I am trying to do it.

```js
var el = document.getElementById(“inputEl”);

el. addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  console.log(‘inside this block’);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: PLease add your html to make it a [mre].

Comment: What errors do you get in your console? Also, don't use curly quotes `“inputEl”`

Comment: Nothing wrong here. This is fine. Do replace your fancy quotes with standard single or double quotes though

Comment: `el. addEventListener` there's a space between the dot and the "a", they should be together as in `el.addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

Change your js as below:

```
var el = document.getElementById("inputEl");

el.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  console.log('inside this block');
});
```

And also place your .js file at the **bottom** in your index.html